# Ant ignore files from build

Tags: java, android, ant, android-ndk

I want to compile my project with ant javac,regarding some of my java files have errors, i don't want to compile them, i have to override ant `"-compile"` task and add `excludes="**/Global.java"` in order to ignore this file from compile, but in the console i still see compiler wants to compile this file and it show some error in this file.
what is the solution?

```
<target name="-compile" depends="-pre-build, -build-setup, -code-gen, -pre-compile">
        <do-only-if-manifest-hasCode elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping...">
            <!-- merge the project's own classpath and the tested project's classpath -->
            <path id="project.javac.classpath">
                <path refid="project.all.jars.path" />
                <path refid="tested.project.classpath" />
                <path path="${java.compiler.classpath}" />
            </path>
            <javac encoding="${java.encoding}"
                source="${java.source}" target="${java.target}"

                debug="true" extdirs="" 
                includeantruntime="false"
                excludes="**/Global.java"
                destdir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
                bootclasspathref="project.target.class.path"
                verbose="${verbose}"
                classpathref="project.javac.classpath"
                fork="${need.javac.fork}">
                <src path="${source.absolute.dir}" />
                <src path="${gen.absolute.dir}" />



                <compilerarg line="${java.compilerargs}" />
            </javac>

        </do-only-if-manifest-hasCode>
    </target>
```

file path :  `/Users/username/Desktop/projects/Android/phone-android/src/org/phone/Global.java`

Comment: Is there a space missing before `excludes`? Looks like it is following the  `"false"` without space inbetween

Comment: I have updated my codes, please check it

Comment: I still see `includeantruntime="false"excludes="**/` with no space

Comment: it have space in real code,